# Getting this error " ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed" while importing tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, while-loop

I have python 3.7.8, I have installed virtual environment and then tensorflow. But when I tried to import it, I got an error `"ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed."`

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I also tried installing conda but no change.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing vs2019 redistributable libraries
It is required for tf 2.3

[visual studio resitributable download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: I already have it. I also tried different versions of tensorflow but nothing worked